# Column in field list is ambiguous despite I have correct table names

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Here's the code, in theory this should work, right? But when I run this, the error comes up

"#1052 - Column 'spotID' in field list is ambiguous"

```
SELECT start, end, spotID FROM bookings
    INNER JOIN glampingspot ON (bookings.spotID = glampingspot.spotID)
    WHERE glampingspot.venueID = 1 
    AND glampingspot.maxPeople >= 3
```

And yes I am 1000% sure that the names of the tables are "bookings" and "glampingspot", and they have the same key "spotID"

Comment: this is exactly why the error is being shown. Think about it, if 2 columns in different tables have the same name, how would you decide which one to show in the output?

Comment: Ohh I get it now, I thought the tables would be merged into 1 using INNER JOIN. It works now ‍♂️

Comment: Also, it's a good coding practice to qualify all columns with the source table / or alias when using a JOIN. That way it's clear just by looking at the query which columns belong to which tables.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952). Asserting *yes, I am 1000% sure* (which is impossible, as there is nothing more than 100%) is useless noise. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting, as was suggested when you created your account.

Comment: @KenWhite sorry for using an impossible hyperbole in a programming question! And if you see a question that is easily answerable, you can just ignore it instead of telling me to read the beginner guide even though my question was neither irrelevant nor subjective :)

Comment: Your question is not *totally answerable* without seeing your DB schema (table definitions). This site requires that you provide the relevant details, as you can see if you follow the links I provided to the [tour] and [help], which clearly you still have not yet done. If you can't be bothered to provide the relevant information needed to answer your question, you shouldn't be asking it here. If you didn't need a beginner's guide, you would have provided those details in the first place, which you didn't. Ergo, the beginner's guide is an appropriate suggestion.

Comment: And for future reference: When someone with more experience here tries to educate you on how the site works, the appropriate response is *Thank you!". You're welcome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT start, end, bookings.spotID FROM bookings
    INNER JOIN glampingspot ON (bookings.spotID = glampingspot.spotID)
    WHERE glampingspot.venueID = 1 
    AND glampingspot.maxPeople >= 3
```

It is always a good practice to resolve the scope of columns so that it is clear that which column comes from which table in the output.

Comment: The answer would be better if it demonstrated good practices by qualifying *all* columns with the source table or alias :-)

Comment: agreed. but since the table structures were unknown, I just focused on the problem at hand.

Comment: If the table structures are unknown, you should not be answering the question because it's missing necessary information.